# Remove the weekend days from the event log - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Could you please help me with the following tackle?

I need to remove the weekend days from the dataframe (attached link: [dataframe_running_example](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbnkydzZ5cnpRTEVpTXVfbHQwY0tvR3RTLXc3Z3xBQ3Jtc0trM1V6YTl3TGNVdEVQQmRHVWVyS2FfSmpHYkFZWHlVY1VfdlhJMlZnSjNGUm9oUThBcWN4b0tIcHhMQ2lZTFpESEhqUzFZSWJrb01VZGVpMF8tb0steDFObmhBUXNhU1h4Nk42WHhVQXVBWmloYURwbw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fpm4py.fit.fraunhofer.de%2Fstatic%2Fassets%2Fdata%2Fgetting_started%2Frunning-example.csv). I can get a list of all the weekend days between mix and max date pulled out from the event however I cannot filter out the df based on "list_excluded" list.

```
  from datetime import timedelta, date
  import pandas as pd
    
    #Data Loading
    df= pd.read_csv("running-example.csv", delimiter=";")
    df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
    df["timestamp_date"] = df["timestamp"].dt.date
    
    def daterange(date1, date2):
        for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
            yield date1 + timedelta(n)
    
    #start_dt & end_dt
    start_dt = df["timestamp"].min()
    end_dt = df["timestamp"].max()
    print("Start_dt: {} & end_dt: {}".format(start_dt, end_dt))
    
    weekdays = [6,7]
    
    #List comprehension
    
    list_excluded = [dt for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt) if dt.isoweekday() in weekdays]
    df.info()
    df_excluded = pd.DataFrame(list_excluded).rename({0: 'timestamp_excluded'}, axis='columns')
    df_excluded["ts_excluded"] = df_excluded["timestamp_excluded"].dt.date
    df[~df["timestamp_date"].isin(df_excluded["ts_excluded"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

ooh an issue has been resolved. I used pd.bdate_range() function.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Wczytanie danych
df= pd.read_csv("running-example.csv", delimiter=";")
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
df["timestamp_date"] = df["timestamp"].dt.date

#Zakres timestamp: start_dt & end_dt
start_dt = df["timestamp"].min()
end_dt = df["timestamp"].max()
print("Start_dt: {} & end_dt: {}".format(start_dt, end_dt))

bus_days = pd.bdate_range(start_dt, end_dt)
df["timestamp_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp_date"])
df['Is_Business_Day'] = df['timestamp_date'].isin(bus_days)
df[df["Is_Business_Day"]!=False]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).